# Why does naiveBayes return all NA's for multiclass classification in R?

Tags: r

Started to write this question, and then figured out the answer. Going to put it here for posterity, since it was hard to find answers on this.

I'm trying to use the naiveBayes classifier from the e1071 package. It seems to have no trouble generating *predictions* for new data, but I actually need the probability estimates for the classes of the new data.

Example:

```
> model <- naiveBayes(formula=as.factor(V11)~., data=table, laplace=3)
> predict(model, table[,1:10]) 
[1] 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 1 1 1 3 3 1 1
> predict(model, table[,1:10], type="raw")
       1  2  3  4
 [1,] NA NA NA NA
 [2,] NA NA NA NA
 [3,] NA NA NA NA
 [4,] NA NA NA NA
 [5,] NA NA NA NA
 [6,] NA NA NA NA
 [7,] NA NA NA NA
 [8,] NA NA NA NA
 [9,] NA NA NA NA
[10,] NA NA NA NA
[11,] NA NA NA NA
[12,] NA NA NA NA
[13,] NA NA NA NA
[14,] NA NA NA NA
[15,] NA NA NA NA
```

This seems absurd to me, since the fact that the model is able to output predictions means it must have probability estimates for the classes. What is causing this strange behaviour?

Some things I've already tried without success:

- adding type="raw" to the model construction call.
- Using the NaiveBayes function from the klaR package instead (which cannot handle the .

An example of some data which produces this error:

```
table[1:5,]
  V1 V2       V3         V4        V5        V6        V7        V8        V9
1  0  0 0.000000  0.0000000  0.000000 0.0000000 0.6711444 0.7110409 0.0000000
2  0  0 0.000000  0.0000000 -1.345804 2.1978370 0.6711444 0.7110409 0.0000000
3  0  0 1.923538 -3.6718725  0.000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.8980172
4  0  0 1.923538 -0.4079858  0.000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.8980172
5  0  0 0.000000  0.0000000 -1.345804 0.2930449 0.6711444 0.7110409 0.0000000
         V10 V11
1  0.0000000   6
2  0.0000000   3
3 -3.1316213   2
4 -0.2170431   5
5  0.0000000   4
```

Comment: To make it more reproducible, it'd be great if you could add some data with which we could work out to the same error.

Comment: @Arun sure. I'll put some up now.

Comment: thanks you for taking my suggestions into account. One thing. You mention `as.factor(V17)` in your code, but there are 11 columns in the data.. Am I missing something here or should there be more columns in `table`? Also `dput(head(table))` maybe better to copy/paste your data for others to reproduce.

Comment: @Arun I've changed the example code to be more consistent. The sets are produced by a streaming process and discarded shortly afterwards, so I no longer have either of these actually.

Comment: Thanks a lot,  type="raw" worked for me :), i dont still understand anything about the answer though :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is happening because one of the classes in the dataset has only one instance.

An easy fix for my application was to clone that record and add a tiny amount of noise, after which predict works as expected.

Edit: it actually seems the addition of noise is not always required. Here's a really simple example that resolves the dataset posted in the question, by simply adding an extra copy of every row in the table:

```
> table <- as.data.frame(rbind(as.matrix(table),as.matrix(table))
> nms <- colnames(table)
> model <- naiveBayes(table[,1:length(nms)-1], factor(table[,length(nms)]))
> predict(model, table[,1:(length(nms)-1)], type='raw')
                 2            3            4            5            6
 [1,] 2.480502e-34 6.283185e-12 6.283185e-12 2.480502e-34 1.000000e+00
 [2,] 1.558542e-45 9.999975e-01 2.506622e-06 1.558542e-45 6.283170e-12
 [3,] 1.000000e+00 1.558545e-45 1.558545e-45 6.283185e-12 2.480502e-34
 [4,] 6.283185e-12 1.558545e-45 1.558545e-45 1.000000e+00 2.480502e-34
 [5,] 1.558542e-45 2.506622e-06 9.999975e-01 1.558542e-45 6.283170e-12
 [6,] 2.480502e-34 6.283185e-12 6.283185e-12 2.480502e-34 1.000000e+00
 [7,] 1.558542e-45 9.999975e-01 2.506622e-06 1.558542e-45 6.283170e-12
 [8,] 1.000000e+00 1.558545e-45 1.558545e-45 6.283185e-12 2.480502e-34
 [9,] 6.283185e-12 1.558545e-45 1.558545e-45 1.000000e+00 2.480502e-34
[10,] 1.558542e-45 2.506622e-06 9.999975e-01 1.558542e-45 6.283170e-12
```

Comment: And instead of saying it in words, if you could share the code, then it'd be much more useful. If you could implement both my suggestions, I'd be happy to +1 both Q&A.

Comment: It is not clear what was causing the issue, and why it was resolved.